# Same Browser but different windows, do they share cookies?

Tags: session, cookies, session-cookies

Looking at other questions asked previously here, it is clear that:

1. Different Browsers maintain their own cookies.
2. Same Browser, but different tabs, share cookies (unless specifically code it).

But what happens if it same browser but different windows (previous window is not closed), do they share cookies or each window maintain their own cookie?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they share cookies. You can see this clearly if you login to a site in one window and then load the same site in another: because they share cookies you will already be logged in.