# Call common api before intercept fires

Tags: angular, interceptor, angular-httpclient-interceptors

My interceptor code:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {
      HttpInterceptor,
      HttpRequest,
      HttpHandler,
      HttpEvent,
      HttpErrorResponse,
      HttpHeaders,
      HttpResponse
    } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
    import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { ApiService } from 'src/app/modules/services/api.service';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class HttpErrorService implements HttpInterceptor {
      constructor(
        private apiService: ApiService,
        private router: Router,
      ) { }
    
      intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>,next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    
        request = request.clone({
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':  'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
          })
        });
        
        return this.apiService.getSession().subscribe((res:any)=>{
           if(res.data.existingSession == 'active'){
              this.router.navigate(['/login']);
           } else{
            return next.handle(request).pipe(
              map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                return event;
              }),
              catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                return throwError(() => { return 'Something bad happened; please try again later.' })
              }));
           }
        });
    
    
      }
    }
```

I am trying to call an api before the interceptor intercept each api calls. But I am unable to add the valid return type & getting this error:

**Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<HttpEvent>': source, operator, lift, subscribe, and 3 more**

Tried with **switchMap**.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpErrorResponse,
  HttpHeaders,
  HttpResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/modules/services/api.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpErrorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService,
    private router: Router,
  ) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = request.clone({
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
      })
    });

    return this.apiService.getSession().pipe(
      switchMap((res: any) => {
        if(res.data.existingSession == 'active'){
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        } else{
          return next.handle(request).pipe(
            map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
              return event;
            }),
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
              return throwError(() => 'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
            })
          );
        })
        }
    );
  }
}
```

It's triggering the interceptor  n number of time. But api calls are not happening. **I need to call 1 api before interceptor intercepts each api calls.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is code example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nxafkd?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest.interceptor.ts) based on code you provided in your question. I think this would solved your problem.

If you want to use service api in interceptor I think you need to be sure that this api would be executed without using this interceptor; and the best or default way to do that is to use [HttpBackend](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpBackend). of course you can see usage in this code example.

Just a note, I see you tried to use router.navigate() in your interceptor and I think it's not the best place for this kind of control. I can understand the need to define some logic through interceptor, but if you want to handle route redirection(related to session management) [Angular guard](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) would be better for that.

Hope this could be helpful.

Comment: Happy to hear that !

Answer (score 1):

I tried this example for a long time and then realized its not a good method to do, because, http interceptor is meant to intercept http requests, at the place of intercepting, its not right not make another http call, this will create a never ending loop (sometimes browser will crash)

Ideally, you need to send the auth token during each api call and API call should give `401` (un authorized error) during this, we need to navigate to login page.

If your API does not support auth over each api call, kindly check the auth using a `setInterval` or rxjs `interval` at regular intervals and logout the application

Approach 1 is ideal, but as a temporary fix, you can implement approach 2.

So to summarize, its better not to do this, due to above mentioned reasons!

Comment: Same issue persist again >> None of the api's are triggering.

Comment: My goal is to avoid same user login/session in different browser. For this reason I need to check the user’s session before calling any api. Whats the best way to achieve this??

Comment: @Shankar Please store in cookies, [SO answer for cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49687204/same-browser-but-different-windows-do-they-share-cookies)